# How to determine if it is daytime (light outside?) in python using ephem library

Tags: python, light, pyephem

The [ephem](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/) python library can perfectly determine the next sunrise and sunset.

What I want to know is if it is light outside or not at a certain moment in time. Is there a simple function call in ephem that returns this?

Comment: calculate the sun altitude (`Sun(observer).alt`) for the observer (positive value means the sun is up). Adjust `observer.horizon` for [different definitions of dusk/dawn (twilight)](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/rise-set.html#computing-twilight).

Comment: `if now > sunrise && now < sunset`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this is probably the solution, need to do some tesitng stiil.    if datetime.now() > previous_rising and datetime.now() < next_setting

Comment: `datetime.now()` is the wrong function. Either use `datetime.utcnow()` or `ephem.now()`.  You could write `a < x < b` in Python. `ephem` itself uses something like this internally: `is_up = lambda sun=Sun(observer): (sun.alt + sun.radius  - observer.horizon) > 0`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Organizations like the United States Naval Observatory have definitions for “it is light outside” — you can find the USNO’s definitions here:

http://aa.usno.navy.mil/faq/docs/RST_defs.php

Once you choose the definition you want, ask the `Sun` object for its `alt` and compare that value with the altitude in the definition from the USNO. I strongly recommend that you use the `alt`, as it is fast for PyEphem to compute. If instead you ask about the sunrise and sunset, then you sent PyEphem off on a very expensive iterative search where it has to keep trying different times of day until it finally discovers the moment of sunrise and sunset — which you are really not interested in, it sounds like.  You just want to compare the Sun's altitude to your own threshold for “is it light outside.”

Note that `alt` will be in radians, so you will need to convert your chosen number of degrees before comparing:

import ephem

```
s = ephem.Sun()
sf = ephem.city('San Francisco')
s.compute(sf)
twilight = -12 * ephem.degree
print 'Is it light in SF?', s.alt > twilight
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, very useful and clear. The only thing I don't get yet is the -12 value in the twilight formula. Can you explain this?

Comment: One of the USNO definitions of twilight is when the sun is twelve degrees below the horizon.